# How to force datetime to retain 0 microseconds in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, floating-point, formatting

I need a datetime to retain the microseconds even though they are 0. Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
starttime = datetime(year=2018, month=2, day=15, hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
print(starttime.isoformat())
```

I want that to print with `00.000000` seconds. But it prints with `0` seconds. If I put in 1 microsecond then it will print `00.000001`.

The issue is that I am using a jquery call that requires the iso format with a float in the seconds position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually format it with `strftime`:

```
>>> starttime = datetime(year=2018, month=2, day=15, hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> starttime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
'2018-02-15T08:00:00.000000'
```

Vs:

```
>>> starttime.isoformat()
'2018-02-15T08:00:00'
```

And:

```
>>> starttime = datetime(year=2018, month=2, day=15, hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=1)
>>> starttime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
'2018-02-15T08:00:00.000001'
>>> starttime.isoformat()
'2018-02-15T08:00:00.000001'
```

Answer (score 2):

(Confirmed to work after Python3.6, will NOT work on 2.7)

`isoformat()` accepts an argument:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0).isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
Out[17]: '2020-02-20T00:00:00.000000'
```

possible values:

```
    'auto': the default behaviour
    'hours': '{:02d}'
    'minutes': '{:02d}:{:02d}'
    'seconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'
    'milliseconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:03d}'
    'microseconds': '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:06d}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With a small manipulation of the standard string conversion you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
def force_microseconds(a_datetime):
    dt_str = a_datetime.isoformat()
    if '.' not in dt_str:
        dt_str += '.000000'
    return dt_str
```

#### Test code:

```
import datetime as dt

starttime = dt.datetime(year=2018, month=2, day=15, hour=8,
                        minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print(force_microseconds(starttime))
print(force_microseconds(starttime + dt.timedelta(microseconds=1) ))
```

#### Results:

```
2018-02-15T08:00:00.000000
2018-02-15T08:00:00.000001
```

Comment: the problem i have here is, that at the end its a string, if i want to add afterwards microseconds to the string, i need to parse it back to a datetime object.. then it loses the microseconds again.